# Dojo Datagrid editable cell, constraints not working

Tags: datagrid, dojo

I’m trying to create a Datagrid with editable cells. 
As I am using dijits for the editable cells I try to set constraints within the “widgetProps” property of the layout, like this:

```
   widgetProps: {
       required: true,
       constraints: {
           min: 0,
           max: 100,
           places: '0,2'
       }
   }
```

Here *required: true*  works as expected, whereas the *constraints* property is not working at all.

An example here: http://jsfiddle.net/LjVmJ/ where I've tried to use constraints both in a NumberTextBox and a DateTextBox.

Bug in Dojo or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **From Oliver on the dojo mailinglist:** 
>   It should be "constraint", and it should be put outside "widgetProps".

Which solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found a ‘dirty’ solution to this issue:

First declare my own NumberTextBox with the required constraints:

```
dojo.declare(
    "my.custom.PercentageNumberTextBox", 
    [dijit.form.NumberTextBox],
    {
        postCreate: function(){
            this.inherited(arguments);
            this.set('constraints', {min:0,max:100, places:'0,2'});
    }
});
```

Then I’m using it as the widgetClass in the grid structure:

```
    {
        field: 'employmentPercentage',
        name: 'Employment %',
        type: dojox.grid.cells._Widget,
        widgetProps: { required: true },
        widgetClass: my.custom.PercentageNumberTextBox,
        editable: true,
        width: '150px'
    }
```

This is a workaround for now (full example here: http://jsfiddle.net/LjVmJ/2/),